# why i scanf in c language with int variable of any char and printf with %d it must show 2?

Tags: c, variables, printf, scanf

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int name;
    scanf("%d",&name);
    printf("%d",name);
}
```

Why when I enter "Hello","World","Good", etc it must show 2 ?
Why 2 not the other number ?
If I want to scanf string and printf ASCII code of it how should i do ?
thankyou

Comment: You set up scanf to read a decimal value. You cannot enter strings like that with %d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print ascii values of an entered string :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char array[100];   
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter string : ");
    scanf("%s",array);    // fixed as suggested in comments

    for(i=0;i<strlen(array);i++){

        printf("%d-",array[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code:

```
Enter string : hello
104-101-108-108-111-
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by good folks in the comments ... make sure array size is defined for some value that you think your input size  will never exceed  ...

Comment: To stay on the save side you 'd better do: `scanf("%99s",&array);`.

Comment: Not entirely incorrect, but you're passing the wrong pointer type to `scanf` - it should just be `scanf("%s", array);`. Edit: And you should check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I enter "Hello","World","Good", etc it must show 2 ? Why 2 not the other number ?

This is just because it is invoking Undefined Behavior. You will get anything. Sometimes it will give your desired output. Sometimes it will give my desired output. Sometimes it will give no one's desired output.

> If I want to scanf string and printf ASCII code of it how should i do ?

Use `getchar` function to read your string 'character by character' and then print the ASCII value of each character using `%d` specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name;
    while((name = getchar()) != '\n')
        printf("%c\t%d\n",name,name);
}
```

NOTE: See, in my code I have not used array to store the string. Your string could be of any length.

Comment: This is very elegant and simple. However there is a minor oversight .. what if you need to manipulate the string that was entered some time into the future ... In that case it will be very helpful to have that string stored somewhere

Comment: @sukhvir; There is no oversight. My answer is straight and specific to the question. Second part of question just asked about printing  ASCII values of characters of an string and my answer is specific to that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the return value of `scanf` which is most likely returning an error when you enter something that doesn't look like a number (e.g. `Hello`, `World`, `Good` are all invalid inputs).

That means the variable `name` is not being written so your `printf` call is actually exhibiting undefined behavior (by accessing an uninitialized variable) which probably explains your output of `2`.

Keep in mind though, that because you're invoking undefined behavior, you technically could have gotten anything (it didn't have to be `2`).